# spring cloud properties not retrieved when use docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am facing a weird issue, I create a DockerFile for each of my services (spring-cloud, eureka, my-service), so when I start the docker compose, the spring cloud server starts, eureka starts, but my application is not able to retrieve the configuration from the spring cloud, but when I access the url that appears in the log it works, I am without ideas about how to solve this issue.

Follow my DockerFiles:
spring cloud Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-jre-stretch

RUN ["mkdir", "/root/remote-config-service"]
COPY target/remote-config-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/remote-config-service/

ENTRYPOINT java -jar /root/remote-config-service/remote-config-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 9000 9001
```

eureka Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-jre-stretch

RUN ["mkdir", "/root/eureka-service-discovery"]
COPY target/eureka-service-discovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/eureka-service-discovery/

ENTRYPOINT java -jar /root/eureka-service-discovery/eureka-service-discovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8761
```

my application Docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.2-jre-stretch

ENV PROFILE="dev"

ADD ["target/product-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "product-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 18100 8091
RUN sh -c 'touch /product-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE -jar /product-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]


HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
    CMD curl -f http://localhost:8091/actuator/health || exit 1
```

Docker compose

```
  remote-config-service:
    container_name: remote-config-service
    build: ./remote-config-service
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  eureka-service-discovery:
    build: ./eureka-service-discovery
    container_name: eureka-service-discovery
    hostname: localhost
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8761:8761

  product-api:
    container_name: product-api
    build: ./product-api
    ports:
      - 18000:18000
      - 8091:8091
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service-discovery
      - remote-config-service
      - mysqldb
    restart: on-failure
```

when I try to start my application (product-api) I am facing this error:

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:9000
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:9000. Will be trying the next url if available
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9000/product-api/dev": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

but when I access this url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:9000/product-api/dev
```

it works fine.

Does someone have some idea to help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers cannot communicate with each other over localhost by default, they are isolated from each other networking-wise. That is why you can go to localhost:9000 in your browser but the container can't reach it. The localhost in your container is the loopback address for that container only, not the host. There are a few different networking types (see https://docs.docker.com/network/) but the default type is `bridge`. Bridge network isolates your container from the other container networks on your host and then forwards traffic on one of your hosts ports into the container port (defined by `port: <host>:<container>` entry) There are a couple options to allow containers to communicate with each other:

- Run with `network: host` (not recommended). This will run your containers directly on your host network so they can all communicate with each other over localhost. You can get rid of the `port:` setting if you use this. The container will bind whatever ports the service uses directly to the host (this can also lead to port conflicts if you wanna run multiple containers that use the same port.)
- Use links (deprecated)
- Use user-defined networks https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ (recommended)
  ex docker-compose.yml:

  ```
  version: '3'
  services: 
    service1:
      container_name: service1
      build: .
      networks:
        - servicenet
      ports:
        - 8888:9000

    service2:
      build: .
      container_name: service2
      restart: on-failure
      networks:
        - servicenet
      ports:
        - 8887:8761

    networks:
      servicenet:
  ```

This will allow service1 to communicate with service2 via `http://service1` and vice-versa

Comment: thanks, in my case that was part of a solution, after I configured the network, I start to face an issue with hostnames, and this solution makes everything work as expected.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849859/cant-resolve-hostnames-between-docker-containers